# vue html not rendering when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, innerhtml

I have the code below:

```
var Cat = {
    template: 
        '<span id="user-animal">' +
        '</span>' +
    ,
    methods: {
        getActivityDataForUser(){
            console.log(1);
            document.getElementById("user-animal").innerHTML = '<last-animal v-for="last-animal in last-animals" :last-animal="last-animal"></last-animal>';
        }
    }
};
```

For context, the code above works as intended when last-animal is actually in the template. The variable last-animals is a global variable that is iterated through to display content. It works fine when it is in template and it is properly rendered. However, I want to only render the component when the button is clicked for performance reasons. Can I achieve this? Here is a screenshot of what the browser renders (doesn't iterate using variables and just uses plain text).

[image: img]

Note animals and activites are the same.

Comment: you have to use [Vue-compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) or custom `render` for this need

Comment: This is XY problem. What you're trying to do is overkill. Stick to templates. From the description, this is what v-if is for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Vue-compile or custom render for this need, and here is an example:

```js
let userContainer = `<span id="user-animal">[template]</span>`;

let { data: activityData } = await getActivityDataForUser();

let templateString = userContainer.replace('[template]', `<last-animal v-for="last-animal in last-animals" :last-animal="last-animal"></last-animal>`);

let Cat = {
    render(h){
        return h({
            data(){
                return {
                    activityData: activityData
                }
            },
            components: {
                LastAnimal
            },
            template: templateString
        });
    }
}
```